# Slope of $xe^{-(\frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{|x|})}$ at x =0

Tags: derivatives, slope

Taking the right-hand differential to calculate the slope of $xe^{-(\frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{|x|})}$ to the right of x=0, I got $e^{-\frac{2}{x}}(1 + \frac{2}{x})$, after simplifying it to $xe^{-\frac{2}{x}}$. Every other solution I found was by using the first principle; $\frac{he^{-\frac{2}{h}}-0}{h}$, h~0. This simplifies to $e^{-\frac{2}{h}}$, which is 0 at x=0.

Why did my normal differential fail here? And either way, how do I solve the differential I got, because it's $0\cdot\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After letting $f(x)=xe^{-(\frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{|x|})}$, and $t=\frac{2}{x}$, it follows that
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}(e^{-\frac{2}{x}}(1 + \frac{2}{x}))=\lim_{t\to +\infty}e^{-t}(1 + t)=\lim_{t\to +\infty}\frac{1 + t}{e^t}=0$$
which is equal to your evaluation of $f_+'(0)$ (after extending $f$ at $x=0$ with the value $0$).

It is interesting to note that
$$f'_-(0)=\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{h}{h}=1\not=0$$
and therefore such function is not differentiable at $x=0$, that is $f$ has not a "proper" slope at $x=0$.

Comment: Oh, so while testing differentiability, you don't substitute the exact value of the point, but take two limits, is that it?

Comment: No, evaluating the limit with $h$ is the direct way to find $f'_+(x_0)$, $f'_-(x_0)$. If $\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f'(x)$ exists and it is finite then it is equal to $f'_+(x_0)$. The same for $x\to x_0^-$.

Comment: I think that's what I meant, too. Basically, one checks whether the values of the differential of the function are equal when their x-values approach the value of the considered point, right?

Comment: In general, it is not always true that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x)=f'(x_0)$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668885/derivatives-of-piecewise-differentiable-functions